# Is it possible to get an array out of CoreData in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I have stored some Strings in CoreData (for example names of persons). Now I want to load these names into an array.

```
func loadData() -> Array<String> {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false




    var test = ""
    var DataArray = [String]()

    do {
       let results = try context.fetch(request)


        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                if let firstusername = result.value(forKey: "username") as? String {
                    test = firstusername
                }
                testArray.append(contentsOf: test)
            }

        }
    } catch  {
        print("Roor")
    }
            print(type(of: test))

            return testArray

}
```

I always get this error message: Instance method 'append(contentsOf:)' requires the types 'String' and 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') be equivalent

Comment: Use `append()`, not `append(contentsOf:)`. In your case, it would work if `test` was an array of String.

Answer (score 1):

`append(contentsOf:` expects a sequence of items, you have to use just `append(`, and you should move the append line into the `if let` body

```
if let firstusername = result.value(forKey: "username") as? String {
   testArray.append(firstusername)
}
```

or if you want to append an empty string if there is no name

```
testArray.append((result.value(forKey: "username") as? String) ?? "")
```

Nevertheless your method contains a lot of redundant code, this is sufficient

```
func loadData() throws -> Array<String> {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext    
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")    
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false        
    let results = try context.fetch(request)
    return results.compactMap{ $0.username } 
}
```

It returns the array of names or hands over a potential error.